# Need help to get started with Spring framework

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I want to learn Java EE Spring framwork. So, I downloaded Spring Tool Suite from their site, and I followed this "Hello World" example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm

As you can see, he is importing some .jar files, and I also import them but I dont have antlr-runtime-3.0.1 and commons-logging-1.1.1, or at least I cant find them.

So when I run try to run application, I dont know how to run application, because I have just 2 options: AspectJ/Java and Java application.

Of course, when I try to run app, I get error.

You can take look at screenshoot.

[image]

Comment: Were you expecting another option of how to run it? Normally a Spring Framework based app runs the same way the app would run without Spring.

Comment: I expected some "server" option. Anyway, how can I run application from this tutorial? I have stuck at this for few days. :/

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting?cause the example your trying is very simple and straightfoward . Server option didn't come cause it's not a dynamic web project.It's just simple java project

Comment: I get this one error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good place to go look for jars:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr-runtime

Notice this page has several versions of antlr. If you click the link to 3.0.1, you can download the jar.

There is probably a website for antlr that has the jars but it might not have old ones where they are easy to find.

Similarly for commons-logging, there is an Apache site for it. But you can find it by searching at http://mvnrepository.com though you may have to poke around to find it.

For your second question, run as a Java application. The tutorial has a class MainApp that contains a `main()` method. You use `MainApp` as the starting class and it will begin running the `main()` method's code.

This is standard Java behavior. You might want to run through some simple Java tutorials to learn how plain old Java works and then add Spring Framework when you are a bit more proficient.

Comment: I will download these .jar fiels, and I will import them. So, if do it successfully, I will accept this answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

In your case the Java Application runner is appropriated cause you're indeed writing a java application.
The tutorial you're following specify to install first spring and commons-logging API.
(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_environment_setup.htm) You will then be able to find the expected libraries in the APIs installation folders.
I would recommand to use maven for every java project, it will allow you to easly manage your dependencies.